# How to filter a sublist inside parent and return parent with sublist filtered

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to create a linq to sql query that will return a list of objects with a sublist that has been filtered.

It sounds easy but I'm not sure how to make this to work

Here the SQL Query which returns what I want:

```
select * from Texts t inner join Translations tt on t.TranslationId = tt.Id 
inner join Pages p on tt.Id = p.TranslationId and tt.NeutralText = p.TitleNeutralTextId
where t.LanguageId = 1
```

Now I have to write this with linq.

What I've done so far is:

```
var query = this.Queryable() // Page entity
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.TitleTranslation.Texts);

            return (from m in query
                    from l in m.TitleTranslation.Texts
                    where m.TitleTranslation.Texts.Any(l => l.LanguageId == 1)
                    select m);
```

But it didn't work because I got the sublist with all languages instead of language with id #1 only.

Thanks for helping,

David

Comment: Consider the rules in my [SQL to LINQ recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786), especially rule 6.

Comment: For EF I think you need to use the `.Query` method to [filter loading related entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I wanted thanks to Hasnain Bukhari.
The solution was to start from the text table, assign the filter, include the desired Entity (*Page*) and put the results into memory (*ToList()*). Then select pages. It will give the result I want in the order I have to.

```
var query = textService.Queryable()
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Include(x => x.Translation.Pages)
               .Where(x => x.LanguageId == languageId).ToList();

return query.SelectMany(x => x.Translation.Pages);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any specific reason you are writing query? Either you can use `Eager Loading` of EF to load all the child tables, Or below Linq statement can fetch the required result

```
    var result = texts.Join(translations, t => t.TranslationId, tt => tt.Id, (t, tt) => new {t, tt})
        .Join(pages, ttt => new { Id = ttt.tt.Id, NeutralTextId = ttt.tt.NeutralText }, p => new { Id = p.TranslationId, NeutralTextId = p.TitleNeutralTextId }, (ttt, p) => new {ttt, p})
        .Where(tttt => tttt.ttt.t.LanguageId == 1);
```

Here replace `texts`, `translations` and `pages` with actual dbContext entities collection property.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must try lime this. this will work for you .
This will be similar to sql query

One way to do this .

```
var result = from m in Texts
join Translations on Texts.TranslationId = Translation.Id
Join Pages on Translations.NeutralText = Pages.NeutralText
where Texts.LanguageId = 1
select m
```

There an other way to do this using entity framework

```
var result =       
this.Queryable().AsNoTracking().Include(x=>x.Translations).Where(x=>x.LanguageId= 1)
```